# Finding the next 3 occurences after an event is completed - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Need some help with this query please. We have events (drives) that take place at accounts (places) and once they happened, they are marked complete (status id = 2) in the database.

For this query, I'd like to be able to search for a particular account, find the last time an event was completed at this account, and then find the next three confirmed (status id = 1) events that will occur at this account.

I'm not exactly sure how to handle this. I'm guessing some sort of sub-query but I am having some trouble starting.

What I have so far is:

```
select 
    dm.driveid, dm.fromdatetime, dm.statusid, stat.statustext, acct.internalname
from 
    rpt_drivemaster dm
inner join 
    rpt_accounts acct on dm.accountid = acct.accountid
inner join 
    rpt_drivestatusdef stat on dm.statusid = stat.statusid
where 
    acct.accountid = '17708'
    and dm.fromdatetime >= dateadd(month, -1, getdate())
    and dm.statusid not in (3,5,6)
order by 
    dm.fromdatetime;
```

This will give me all drives for this account going back a month and looking forward.  But what I would like it to actually do is only give me the next three drives (1/28/15, 2/4/15, 2/18/15).

[image]

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with completes as (
    select dm.driveid, dm.fromdatetime, dm.statusid, stat.statustext, acct.internalname
    from rpt_drivemaster dm
    inner join rpt_accounts acct on dm.accountid=acct.accountid
    inner join rpt_drivestatusdef stat on dm.statusid=stat.statusid
    where acct.accountid='17708'
    and dm.fromdatetime >= dateadd(month,-1,getdate())
    and dm.statusid = 2
),
confirmed as (
    select top(3) dm.driveid, dm.fromdatetime, dm.statusid, stat.statustext, acct.internalname
    from rpt_drivemaster dm
    inner join rpt_accounts acct on dm.accountid=acct.accountid
    inner join rpt_drivestatusdef stat on dm.statusid=stat.statusid
    inner join completes as c
    on c.accountid = dm.accountid
    and dm.fromdatetime > c.fromdatetime
    where dm.statusid = 1
    order by dm.fromdatetime
)
select * from completed
union
select * from confirmed
order by fromdatetime;
```